# How to get profile information after login

Tags: php

I have a standard register.php and login.php. When I register I put all the information in a database and I recall them after I click the submit button at the login page. When the username and password are the same as a username and password in my database then it will go to the page where my profile information should come. Lets call it profile.php. I dont know how to get the information(username) from the login.php and show the profile information from the username in the profile.php. How do I check the username from the login.php and show the information that belongs to the username in the profile.php?(let's just first show the username, I will figure out the rest of the information myself.)

Comment: we cant show anything without seeing what code you're working with.

Comment: @sevenseacat I dont want you to use my code but I just need an example of how to do this.

Comment: Kind of a stupid downvote. I dont want people to just custom make it with my code. I just need a solution of how to do it...

Comment: No-one here cares about stealing your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Login and get user information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084481/php-login-and-get-user-information?rq=1)

Comment: @sevenseacat it's not about stealing my code, I just want to make it myself...

Comment: The downvote really doesn't make sense. Just because I didn't put code in it, while it's not needed? People understood the question and it got answered. I described it detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use sessions - either built in or custom made.

read: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

---

in all *.php files, add `session_start();`

in login.php, after successful login use `$_SESSION["user_name"] = $_POST["user_name"];`

in profile.php, check if `$_SESSION["user_name"]` is set.

Comment: Where should I put the session_start();?

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate it. Take my upvote. I will take a look into the sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [$_Post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [$_Get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to submit the username to another page and get there the userinformations via SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on sessions in php as you will need something like that to track if a user is logged in.

After reading up on sessions this is what you will have to do.

In the php function thats doing the login you should create a session and store something in it, preferable the user id, then on the profile page you can access the user id from the session and get the data from the database.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php